# how to remove 403 error

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, shared-hosting, http-status-code-403

Everytime I try to access this url http://mysite.com/somefile.php?url=http://google.com

I get Forbidden error, how I can solve this issue using .htaccess file. I am on shared hosting so all I can do it edit the .htaccess file and nothing else. Please tell me solution that can be implemented using the .htaccess file.

Comment: If I try to access http://mysite.com/somefile.php?url= , then it works fine, I cant add some url after = .

Comment: Try encode the `/` by `%2F`

Comment: it didn't work http://mysite.com%2Fsomefile.php?url=http://google.com

Comment: Not **that** slash -- the others in query string: `http:%2F%2Fgoogle.com` .. although it should work without encoding anyway.

Comment: the others were already encoded, The thing is I cannot use any url after the "="

Comment: Please contact your hoster -- maybe they have some special security restrictions in place. I personally see no obvious reasons why it should not work.

Comment: And what does your error log say?

Comment: I can just see the error logs via cpanel, and there is not much information about error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting bitten by your hosting provider's `mod_security` rules; the pattern of your URL is a common one associated with attempting to exploit PHP file include vulnerabilities, which are (still, unfortunately) one of the most common and easy to exploit vulnerability classes.

You can talk to your provider, or fix your application.